# VS Team Services & Git for Windows error "fatal: Authentication failed ..."

Tags: git, azure-devops, msysgit

Running Git for Windows and the Git Credential Manager on a shared, 4 user, developer VM.

Upon cloning a repository, the GCM kicks in and authenticates me, but Git still reports `fatal: Authentication failed ...`

I can see in my Team Services (previously VSO) account that the GCM created a new personal access token:

`Git: https://company.visualstudio.com/ on SHARED-VM-HOSTNAME`

I've revoked previous ones and it creates a new one, so that mechanism is working.

Git (version 2.10) and the GCM don't seem to be playing ball. We have it working elsewhere on other machines.

It works for only one shared user RDP'ed onto this VM.

Just asking IT to reinstall latest versions of all software (again, again).

IP web traffic I think is routing directly/no proxy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague sent me the wrong Git repository URL!

Bad version:

`https://oursubdom.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/SomeProjectII`

Good version:

`https://oursubdom.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/SomeProjectII`

Not the first time he's done that, either. Ugh.

Comment: Aside: the MS VSO login UI has a bug where the login button does nothing, click back and then enter your email address again and it'll work.